# Run Mongo find Synchronously

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, csv, papaparse

I have a problem where I've got 20+k rows in a csv file and I'm trying to update them based on documents of a matching field in a Mongo DB that contains 350k docs.

The trick is that I need to perform some logic on the matches and then re-update the csv.

I'm using PapaParse to parse/unparse the csv file

Doing something like works to get all my matches

```
const file = fs.createReadStream('INFO.csv');
Papa.parse(file, {
    header: true,
    complete: function(row) {        
        getMatchesAndSave(row.data.map(el => { return el.fieldToMatchOn })); 
    }
});`

function getMatchesAndSave(fields) {
Order.find({fieldToMatchOn: { $in: fields}}, (err, results) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(results);
});
```

}

That gets me matches fast. However, I can't really merge my data back into the csv bc the csv has a unique key column that Mongo has no idea about.

So all the data is really dependent of what's in the csv.

Therefore I thought of doing something like this

`

```
const jsonToCSV = [];
for (let row of csvRows) {
    db.Collection.find({fieldToMatchOn: row.fieldToMatchOn}, (err, result) => {
        //Add extra data to row based on result
        row.foo = result.foo;

        //push to final output
        jsonToCSV.push(row);
    }
}
papa.unparse(jsonToCSV);
//save csv to file
```

The issue with the above implementation (as terribly inefficient as it may seem) - is that the Find calls are asynchronous and nothing gets pushed to jsonToCSV.

Any tips? Solving this with $in would be ideal, are there any ways to access the current element in the $in (so looking for the iterator)..that way I could process on that.

Comment: Try to use async await to get the results then push it to the jsonToCSV array.

Comment: May you please provide an example. I see to use asyn await in a lot of posts but it doesn't seem to work. I think it's due to the for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try async/await to iterate csvRows array,  like this:

```js
const search = async () => {
  const jsonToCSV = await Promise.all(csvRows.map(async row => {
/* find returns a promise, so we can use await, but to use await is 
mandatory use it inside an async function. Map function not returns a 
promise, so this can be solve using Promise.all. */
    try {
      const result = await db.Collection.find({ fieldToMatchOn: row.fieldToMatchOn });
      row.foo = result.foo;
      return row;
    } catch (e) {
      // do somenthing if error
    }
  }));
  papa.unparse(jsonToCSV);
}

// call search function
search();
```

Check this https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await-array-map to a better understanding.

Comment: This works, although it's looking like I should probably just use IN bc find in a for loop is still not recommended and is still slow.

May you please give a brief explanation of what exactly the code is doing.

Comment: @user2402616 indeed is an inefficient solution loop through an array, and search for items using "find" method for each row of you CSV. I don't understand very well what do you need to do, but seems like you need to search some item inside collection and then update CSV with new fields. Is that right? I did edit my answer with comments to explain a little the code.

Comment: yeah, that's essentially what I'm trying to do. Would be great if I could somehow update my JSON using the IN - but I don't see how that's possible

Comment: @user2402616 I really think that what are you trying to do is quite impossible. Maybe you should use the step function while parsing the CSV. Take a look in this option on documentation [link](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config)

Comment: Yeah step was the first way I tried how to do this. But I still ran into the async issues.

Comment: Ok, so as I said, using IN inside collection query is not possible, because as you said in your first question you can't match each element of your query result with the exact row inside your CSV. The data inside CSV must be related with docs inside the collection  by a unique key so that you can modify the correct row within the CSV

Comment: @Gabriel..mm just wondering if it was possible. Yeah, I figured I'd have to first introduce a unique key into the Cllection for the csv